No rerender triggered when changing state
I'm new to react and am having a issue when trying to reset array back to its initial state. The array does update correctly when applying the changes, however no re-render is triggered.
I tried to put in a completely new array so that it was obvious that it was a new array being put it but that didn't work either.
Here are the relevant parts of the code:
const handleClear = (
  setInkomsten: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any[]>>,
  setUitgaven: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any[]>>,
  initialInkomsten: any[],
  initialUitgaven: any[],
  setDummy: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<number>>
) => {
  console.log("Clear button clicked");
  localStorage.clear();
  
  // Create new arrays by copying the initial values
  const newInkomsten = [...initialInkomsten];
  const newUitgaven = [...initialUitgaven];
  
  // Update state with new arrays
  setInkomsten(newInkomsten);
  setUitgaven(newUitgaven);
  
  // Set localStorage with initial values
  localStorage.setItem("Inkomsten", JSON.stringify(newInkomsten));
  localStorage.setItem("Uitgaven", JSON.stringify(newUitgaven));
  
  console.log("Local storage:", localStorage);
  // Force a re-render
  setDummy(prev => prev + 1);
};

export default handleClear;

Relevant parts of the main code:
function App() {
  const initialInkomsten = [
    "Inkomsten",
    "Boodschappen",
    "Dierenvoeding",
    "Activiteiten",
    "Gokken",
  ];
  const initialUitgaven = [
    "Uigaven",
    "Kleren",
    "Dierenvoeding",
    "Spelen",
    "Gokken",
  ];

  const [dummy, setDummy] = useState<number>(0);

  const [inkomsten, setInkomsten] = useState(initialInkomsten);
  const [uitgaven, setUitgaven] = useState(initialUitgaven);

Relevant part of the helper function:
const InputContainer: React.FC<InputContainerProps> = ({
  information,
  color,
  storageKey,
}) => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState<string[]>(() => {
    const savedInput = localStorage.getItem(storageKey);
    return savedInput ? JSON.parse(savedInput) : information;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(storageKey, JSON.stringify(inputValue));
    console.log(inputValue);
  }, [inputValue, storageKey]);

I tried completely renewing the array with no success. I also added a dummy state that would get incremented when the clear button would be pressed but this also doesn't trigger a re render.
I tried directly putting the new arrays in Local Storage and logging them which came back successful but still no rerender

What does the call to handleClear look like? How do you know it's getting called?

I've tested the call to handleClear by using console log statements. Furthermore when i refresh the page manually the array does go back to how it is supposed to look.

What does the call to handleClear look like?

What makes you say that the component isn't rerendering? And which component is that, and how are you rendering your state values that you're updating?

This is what the call looks like:           <button             className="clearButton"             type="button"             onClick={() =>               handleClear(                 setInkomsten,                 setUitgaven,                 initialInkomsten,                 initialUitgaven,                 setDummy               )             }           >             Clear           </button>

The component isn't rerendering because the page doesn't remove the added columns. This is what it looks like when 3 blank columns are added. They should be removed by the Clear button which they are only after the page is manually refreshed: https://ibb.co/4gn7zS2 I am rendering my state values that i am updating via  a helper function input_container. You can see the full code here: https://github.com/ZiaadNegm/IncomeDivider/blob/master/my-react-app/src/input_container.tsx The components are mainly created in the return statement.

@Ziaad Yeah, your InputContainer component is mapping and rendering the values of inputValue. Changing inkomsten or uitgaven isn't going to update inputValue, so what InputContainer displays won't change.
